# How to look up data from a password-protected database on MS Access into Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, passwords, lookup

Simply put, I have an Excel file including columns A, B, C in which A is "ID". In Access file, I have some columns one of which is "ID".
Each week, data at Access and Excel will be updated (new rows will be added below) at unparalleled point of time.

Here's an example:
Excel file:

> ID | Date | Bid 
>   Access file: ID | Winning Bid | Winning Bidder

**Question:** How can I automate the process through which whenever new data is updated on columns A,B,C in the Excel file, it will immediately look up the value in column "`ID`" of Access file and output to columns D, E,... on Excel the values of "Winning Bid" and "Winning Bidder" columns from Access file?

FYI, I'm thinking about writing a `VBA` code but it got an error "Invalid password". I'm totally new to VBA, so I just copied existing code somewhere on the Internet... and it didn't work. So I really need some instructions to build it from scratch. Thank you!!

p/s: My laptop uses MS Office Professional Plus 2013. The order of columns as in my codes reflects the real database, so you don't need to bother about that.

I tried writing VBA code as below...

```
Sub ddd()
Dim wj As Workspace
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set wj = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
Set db = wj.OpenDatabase("R:\Auction\Price Trend.accdb")

stConn = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
& "Data Source=R:\Auction\Price Trend.accdb" & stDB & ";" _
& "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Reauction"

cnt.Open stConn

For Each ce In Range("X3:X" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select [Auction results].[Total Cost in : USD], [Auction results].[unit price], [Auction results].[Winner] from [Auction results] where [Lot Name] = '" & ce.Value & "'")
ce.Offset(0, 6).Value = rs.Fields("Winning Lot Bid")
ce.Offset(0, 8).Value = rs.Fields("Winning Unit Bid")
ce.Offset(0, 7).Value = rs.Fields("Winning Bidder")
Set rs = Nothing

Next ce
Set db = Nothing
Set wj = Nothing

End Sub
```

==> Error message "`Invalid password`"

Comment: Instead of quoting your code, can you please paste it and mark with the code tags (`{}`)?  That would help us better understand it.

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, I've just edited as above. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, assuming that you have the correct password, you might need to surround it in quotes? `... & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=""Reauction"""`

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, I added as you advised but the same error shown up. Btw, maybe this is a silly question but I'm wondering why we should double the ", instead of use only single one?
FYI, when I tried a single ", like this "Reauction", it shown "Compile error: Expected: End of statement".

Comment: Let's say you want to add `"Lucy" is my name` in cell `A1` via VBA.  If you do `Range("A1").Value = ""Lucy" is my name"`, you'll get an error.  When wanting to display (or use) quotes as part of some string, you have to double up --> `Range("A1").Value = """Lucy"" is my name"` would work.  Does that make sense?  For a test, try not breaking that up on multiple lines and just do: `stConn = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=R:\Auction\Price Trend.accdb" & stDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Reauction"`  or `...Password=""Reauction"""`.  Edit: **OH!**, where do you declare and define `stDB`??

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Comment: For stDB, I'm afraid that I haven't declared and defined it. I'm sorry, I'm too new in this...

Comment: what do you expect it to be? You're inserting it in your connection string.

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, I honestly don't get it... like how I should define it and where it should be inserted... I'm sorry, I'm too new to VBA.

Comment: It should likely be a String (`Dim stDB as String`), but for *what* it should be, I don't know.  What do you expect `stConn `  to be when it's used in `cnt.Open stConn`?  Edit: Also, you haven't declared `cnt`...Add `Option Explicit` to the VERY top of your code (above *everything else*). This will force you to declare it.  Your code as shown here is incomplete...

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, can you help suggest me how to modify the code? Honestly your comments seem to make sense to me, but I don't know how to fix it.. Thank you.